# JW Player wrong subtitle position

Tags: jwplayer

I update my player from jw6 to jw7 but positions of subtitles are wrong. I couldn't find any positioning code in jw player files how can i edit it?
They showing a little bit(about 50 or 60px) up compared to older version

Answer (score 0):

I found with Chrome DevTools.
It is in jwplayer.js find you can find id by searching jw-captions.
I changed bottom value 1em from 3em.